# Can I combine these 3 rewrite rules into 1?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having a brain fade and need some help please. I'm using 3 RewriteRules to accomplish something that I think should take just one:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /bar/$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(-*)$ /bar/$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ /bar/$1.html#$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

I need to take the following URLs:

```
http://foo.com/100
http://foo.com/100-1
http://foo.com/200-
http://foo.com/1999
http://foo.com/1999-99
```

...and rewrite them like this:

```
http://foo.com/bar/100.html
http://foo.com/bar/100.html#1
http://foo.com/bar/200.html
http://foo.com/bar/1999.html
http://foo.com/bar/1999.html#99
```

What I have *works* but seems like a bit of a hack. is there a way to combine this all in to one rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to combine all three rules into a single rule, because the replacement structure is not always the same, with hash sometimes appearing and sometimes not appearing.  But you can combine the first two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-?$ /bar/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

The second rule, which replaces with a hash symbol, can remain as is:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ /bar/$1.html#$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. It's so obvious now that you mention combining the first two. Obviously I'd been looking at it too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all 3 rules into one with this trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d+)-?(\d+)?$
RewriteCond %1#%2 ^(\d+)#$ [OR]
RewriteCond %1#%2 ^(\d+)(#\d+)$
RewriteRule ^ /bar/%1.html%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

- In the first condition, we match regex pattern that starts with a number followed by an optional hyphen and another optional number.
- Next two conditions are using `[OR]` so only one will be true.
- For URI `/100`, first condition will be true and `100` will be captured in `%1` but `%2` will be empty.
- For URI `/100-1`, second condition will be true and `100` will be captured in `%1` but `%2` will be `#1`.

Comment: Thank you. I'd actually come up with a similar solution, but was bothered by the hanging '#' in some cases. I know it's harmless to be there, but I was hoping for a magic solution where I could 'one line' the rewrite without the occasional empty#.

Comment: Magic solution is possible to take out empty `#`, will updated in few minutes.